# How do we remove the span tag without lossing data using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have menu structure like below,

```
    <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-34" id="menu-item-34"><a href="http://localhost/artofsujata/testimonials/">
<span class="menu_left">&nbsp;</span> 
<span class="menu_center">Testimonials</span> 
<span class="menu_right">&nbsp;</span>
</a>
</li>   
</ul>
```

i need to remove the  tags without lossing data and i need above menu structrue like below,

```
    <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-34" id="menu-item-34"><a href="http://localhost/artofsujata/testimonials/">
&nbsp; 
Testimonials
&nbsp;
</a>
</li>   
</ul>
```

how can i do this using jquery?..

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308366/remove-element-with-jquery-but-leave-text (jsFiddle showing this approach with this question [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gothick/uzDSa/).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
$('ul li a').html($('ul li a').text());
```

With `$('ul li a').text()` you select all text nodes in your  tag. And with  `$('ul li a').html()` you put all selected text nodes in your  tag. This results in stripping all tags from there.

For multiple LIs you can use this:

```
$('ul.sub-menu > li.menu-item > a').each(function(){
  $(this).html($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: +1. very good. but please use this for multiple lis `$('ul li a').each(function() {$(this).html($(this).text());});`

Comment: @naveen fair comment, i'll add your bit to the answer if you don't mind.

Answer (score 5):

As noted in [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308366/remove-element-with-jquery-but-leave-text), this should do the trick:

```
$("span").contents().unwrap();
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gothick/uzDSa/4/).

Obviously you might want to target this more precisely at your menu to avoid removing other spans on the page:

```
$(".sub-menu li span").contents().unwrap();
```

On the other hand, I'd suggest it might be easier just to change the style of the span in CSS, depending on what your actual problem is.

Comment: Nice answer, i didn't know you could use unwrap() on the text nodes. "I think I've learned something today" (c)Stan :)

Answer (score 0):

Read all the tags, store the data in an array in JS, remove all the tags, and then rewrite the data back out in the format you need?