# Javascript replacing HTML tag using regex matching group

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, ecmascript-6

I have the following string:

```
var x = '<p>Hello there <span contenteditable="false" class="fr-deletable">aaa</span>,<br></p><p>Hi <span contenteditable="false" class="fr-deletable">bbbb</span>,<br></p>';
```

I basically want to strip out all of the `<span></span>` tags but keep the inner content in tact. So the above should turn into:

```
'<p>Hello there aaa,<br></p><p>Hi bbbb,<br></p>';
```

I've tried a few things:

```
x.replace(/<span.*>(.*)<\/span>/g, '$1');
x.replace(/<span.*>/g, '');
```

But none of these gets me what I need. Help please?

Comment: Use `.*?` instead of `.*`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace HTML between two tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40659473/replace-html-between-two-tags)

Comment: @Xufox that doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove element with jQuery but leave text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308366/remove-element-with-jquery-but-leave-text)

Comment: @7ball It does. `x.replace(/<span.*?>(.*?)<\/span>/g, '$1')` gives you precisely the desired result.

Comment: @Xufox's solution works. `<span.*?>|<\/span>`

Comment: @Xufox sorry I thought you only meant inside the tag. It's good. Please write an answer.

Comment: @7ball The duplicate targets already answer your question.

Comment: Haha https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40659473/replace-html-between-two-tags#comment68550224_40659473.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const input = '<p>Hello there <span contenteditable="false" class="fr-deletable">aaa</span>,<br></p><p>Hi <span contenteditable="false" class="fr-deletable">bbbb</span>,<br></p>';
const output = input.replace(/<span [^>]+>([^<]+)<\/span>/g, '$1');
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to do after parsing the HTML, which can be done using jQuery.

```js
var x = '<p>Hello there <span contenteditable="false" class="fr-deletable">aaa</span>,<br></p><p>Hi <span contenteditable="false" class="fr-deletable">bbbb</span>,<br></p>';

console.log(
  $('<div>', {
    html: x
  }).find('span').replaceWith(function() {
    return this.innerHTML;
  }).end().html()
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

**FYI :** [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var x = '<p>Hello there <span contenteditable="false" class="fr-deletable">aaa</span>,<br></p><p>Hi <span contenteditable="false" class="fr-deletable">bbbb</span>,<br></p>';
var y = x.replace(/(<sp|<\/sp)[^>]+>/g, "");
console.log(y);
```